# C# MEF DirectoryCatalog's unexpected result with identical DLL file name

Tags: c#, wpf, mef

I'm developing some WPF application which supports MEF plug-in features. It founds plugin by get exports from DirectoryCatalog, like

```
DirectoryCatalog catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@".\libs", fileName);
CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
BaseModel.Instance.ImportedPlugins = container.GetExports<IExternalServiceProvider>();
```

So basically, I wanted this to load **FILENAME.dll** inside of the sub folder which named **libs**. However, when the dll file named **FILENAME.dll** exists both main folder and libs folder, that code loads **FILENAME.dll** of **main folder**.

```
Debug
ㄴlibs
  ㄴFILENAME.dll(latest build) - This one should be loaded
ㄴApp.exe
ㄴFILENAME.dll(old build) - but this one is loaded instead
```

I tried several scenarios, but it makes me more confusing.

CASE 1

```
Debug
ㄴlibs
  ㄴFILENAME.dll(latest version)
ㄴApp.exe
ㄴFILENAME.dll(old version)
```

**-> old version is loaded**

CASE 2

```
Debug
ㄴlibs
  ㄴFILENAME.dll(latest version)
ㄴApp.exe
ㄴFILENAME.dlllll(old version)
```

**-> latest version is loaded**

CASE 3

```
Debug
ㄴlibs
  ㄴFILENAME.dll(latest version)
ㄴApp.exe
ㄴWRONGFILENAME.dll(old version)
```

**-> latest version is loaded**

**CASE 4 (Most confusing case)**

```
Debug
ㄴlibs
  ㄴWRONGFILENAME.dll or FILENAME.dlllll(latest version)
ㄴApp.exe
ㄴFILENAME.dll(old version)
```

**-> failed to load any of them**

I may try different way of using Catalog to solve this loading problem, but I can't find why and how Case 4 happens. What was I doing wrong?

Comment: DirectoryCatalog works with a search pattern, not a file name. If you are passing in your full file name ("filename.dll"), filename.dlllll or wrongfilename.dll will still match the search pattern, I guess. Also, DirectoryCatalog checks if the given path (".\libs" here) is rooted or not. Can you try with: new DirectoryCatalog(@"libs", "*.dll"); ?

Comment: I tried, and It basically works same... I thought it maybe at least show both of assemblies(old ver and new ver), but it's not...

Comment: It might be a long shot but can you check if there are fusion errors. I've described in [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21069017/578411) some diagnosing steps. The case I handled there seems different from what you describe but maybe the answer helps to get some light in the darkness.If you find something please [edit] it in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I tried fuslogvw and Fusion++, and according to log it seems that default behaivor of assembly loading is working directory first, because its timestamp description shows it attempted to load the right version but its log shows that it finished to find dll when it success to load the dll on the working directory, I ended up to use '''AssemblyCatalog(new Assembly.LoadFrom(path))''' without making sure what happened, because at least it works almost as I intended and I don't have more time to find out. Anyway, thank you for your helping and sorry for no more datas